# Why does "column-count" not work in IE11, since MS says it is fully supported?

Tags: css, ie11-developer-tools

My website is dependent on the css property "column-count" in a number of places. Not only does Caniuse.com show support in IE10 and IE11, but so does the MSDN. Is "column-width" or something else required? The dev tools in IE show a squiggly line under the property, but I don't know what that means. At least, can someone explain what does the squiggly line means and how I should address that?
The site is: http://apurch.jvonhausen.com/learn/
TIA

Comment: Consider several possibilities .. 1. the IE compatibility/page mode is a "legacy" setting (always a possibility); 2. everyone else is wrong (rather unlikely); or 3. the usage (eg. your code) is incorrect and/or contains a syntax error. Anyway, create a *minimal* test-case (eg. a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) and *include* the relevant reproduction code in the question itself.

Comment: So I've created a jsfiddle: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/jannav/4kp3mdcq/) and the same holds. It works well in Chrome, Safari, Firefox. It does not work in IE11.  And, I still do not know what the squiggly line in IE dev tools means.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your browser isn't running in quirks-mode:

- add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11" />` to your markup (anything greater IE=8 will enable support for `column-count`
- even better add an HTTP header `X-UA-Compatible` with value `IE=11`

The first solution might get ignored if your meta tag isn't the first in the HTML header or your browser is configured to run in compatibility mode for e.g. intranet sites. Adding an HTTP header will always work.